# How to get biweek/fornight numbers from dates?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I'm trying to get biweekly/fortnightly numbers for dates.

the weeks can be done like(from documentation):

```
data <- read.csv("dummy data.csv")
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%d-%m-%y")
data$weeks <- format(data$Date, "%U-%Y")
```

this gives:

```
> data
   Date      weeks 
2017-01-07  01-2017
2017-01-08  02-2017
2017-01-15  03-2017
```

I want to calculate biweeks/fortnights from data like i did above.
expected output:

```
   Date      weeks   fortnights
2017-01-07  01-2017   01-2017
2017-01-08  02-2017   01-2017
2017-01-15  03-2017   02-2017
```

How do I do this for a dataframe?

Comment: What is your definition of week in the year?  And note that a given week year can actually span across _two_ years.

Comment: "jan 1 comes in 1st week of year. jan 8, in 2nd week of year." that's my definition. i didn't this part: "a given week year can actually span across two years".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about to get the fortnight, we extract the month which are already passed, multiply it with 2 and add 1 or 2 based on date. So here any date after 14 is considered as next fortnight.

```
(as.integer(format(df$Date, "%m")) - 1) * 2 + 
   (as.integer(format(df$Date, "%d")) > 14) + 1
#[1] 1 1 2
```

If you also want the year we can do

```
paste0((as.integer(format(df$Date, "%m")) - 1) * 2 + 
       (as.integer(format(df$Date, "%d")) > 14) + 1, format(df$Date, "-%Y"))
#[1] "1-2017" "1-2017" "2-2017"
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17173, 17174, 17181), class = "Date"), 
weeks = structure(1:3, .Label = c("01-2017", "02-2017", "03-2017"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **"week"** function from the **"lubridate"** package. e.g.

`lubridate::week(as.Date("2017-06-08"))` will return 23. 
`lubridate::week(as.Date("2017-01-07"))` will return 1. 
`lubridate::week(as.Date("2017-01-08"))` will return 2.

To return the fortnights it will be just a matter of dividing each of the above with the number 2 and **"ceil"** the result e.g.

`ceiling(lubridate::week(as.Date("2017-06-08")) / 2)`

For information on the `ceiling()` function please see the documentation, i.e.
`?ceiling`.

**P.S.** I think in this case it is safer to use the `ceiling()` function instead of the `round()` function, although as long as your arguments are positive, the behaviour will be similar for both.

Comment: I know how to calculate week numbers. If you see my question, it's already there. I want to calculate biweek/fortnight numbers. See my expected output.

Comment: Please see my amended answer and accept it if this answers your question.